# NestJS: present response content from URL on healthcheck

Tags: nestjs, health-check

I'm trying to develop a healthcheck endpoint with NestJS (in which I have no experience). One of the dependencies I want to check is Twilio's SMS service. So far, the best URL I've found to gather this information is https://status.twilio.com/api/v2/status.json. The problem here is that I don't want to merely ping this address, but to gather it's JSON response and present some of the information it provides, namely these:

[image: Twilio status page JSON response]

Is it possible, using (or not) the Terminus module? In the official docs I didn't find anything regarding this, only simpler examples using `pingCheck` / `responseCheck`: https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/terminus

Comment: Why not create a regular `controller` `/status/twillio` endpoint instead of Terminus?

Comment: You've got a point there, I haven't thought of that. However, one of the reasons would be that this health check also checks other dependency, the availability of a Mongo instance (`async () => this.db.pingCheck('database')`). Ideally, this endpoint would present the aggregated information fromf these 2 dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although meanwhile the logic for this healthcheck has changed (and so this question became obsolete), this was the temporary solution I've found, before it happened (basically a regular endpoint using axios, as pointed out in one of the comments above):

**Controller**

```js
    import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { TwilioStatusService } from './twilio-status.service';
    
    @Controller('status')
    export class TwilioStatusController {
      constructor(private readonly twilioStatusService: TwilioStatusService) {}
    
      @Get('twilio')
      getTwilioStatus() {
        const res = this.twilioStatusService.getTwilioStatus();
        return res;
      }
    }
```

**Service**

```ts
    import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
    import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
    
    @Injectable()
    export class TwilioStatusService {
      constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {}
    
      getTwilioStatus() {
        return this.httpService
          .get('https://status.twilio.com/api/v2/status.json')
          .pipe(map((response) => response.data.status));
      }
    }
```

Of course this wasn't an optimal solution, since I had to do this endpoint + a separated one for checking MongoDB's availability (a regular NestJS healthcheck, using Terminus), the goal being an healthcheck that *glued* both endpoints together.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

I have never used this, but `HttpHealthIndicator` has `responseCheck` method to check depends on the API response message. You can specify a callback function to analyze responses from the API. The callback function should return boolean represents the status of the API.

I couldn't find this in the documents, but you can see it [here](https://github.com/nestjs/terminus/blob/d5226a9334abfe1112c523c3b92cdc7214a26025/lib/health-indicator/http/http.health.ts#L85).

Comment: Thanks, as mentioned on the original question, I already looked at `responseCheck` and didn't found how to achieve what I'm looking for, but I'll give another try. Anyway, the challenge here is that I'm not trying to _analyze_ the response, I'm trying to _display_ part of it (underlined in red on the image above).

Comment: Oh, sorry. I misunderstood and overlooked your comment about `responseCheck`. If you want to create something like a proxy to display the original API payload, I guess the easiest way is to create a normal controller and route.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to merge in any property to the resulting object. You can see that in the TypeScript Interface

```ts
/**
 * The result object of a health indicator
 * @publicApi
 */
export declare type HealthIndicatorResult = {
    /**
     * The key of the health indicator which should be uniqe
     */
    [key: string]: {
        /**
         * The status if the given health indicator was successful or not
         */
        status: HealthIndicatorStatus;
        /**
         * Optional settings of the health indicator result
         */
        [optionalKeys: string]: any;
    };
};
```

And here is an example:

###### `diagnostics/health/healthcheck.controller`

```ts
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common'
import { ApiTags } from '@nestjs/swagger'
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios'
import { HealthCheckService, HealthCheck, HealthIndicatorStatus, HealthCheckError } from '@nestjs/terminus'

@ApiTags('diagnostics')
@Controller('diagnostics/health')
export class HealthController {
  constructor(
    private health: HealthCheckService,
    private httpService: HttpService,
  ) { }

  @Get()
  @HealthCheck()
  check() {
    return this.health.check([

      () => this.httpService.get('http://localhost:9002/api/v1/diagnostics/health').toPromise().then(({ statusText, config: { url }, data }) => {
        const status: HealthIndicatorStatus = statusText === 'OK' ? 'up' : 'down'
        return { 'other-service': { status, url, data } }
      }).catch(({ code, config: { url } }) => {
        throw new HealthCheckError('Other service check failed', { 'other-service': { status: 'down', code, url } })
      }),

    ])
  }
}
```

###### `diagnostics/diagnostics.module.ts`

```ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { TerminusModule } from '@nestjs/terminus'
import { HttpModule } from '@nestjs/axios'
import { HealthController } from './health/health.controller'

@Module({
  imports: [
    HttpModule,
    TerminusModule,
  ],
  controllers: [HealthController],
})
export class DiagnosticsModule { }
```